# Combining 2 asyncio based code segments

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-asyncio, autobahn

I'm using the Autobahn asyncio system (to talk the Websocket WAMP protocol), which works fine and I can handle incoming RPC calls and pubsub.
My problem is I now have to connect TCP sockets and send information over these sockets as soon as an RPC call comes in through the Autobahn part.

The autobahn part works fine like this :

```
from autobahn.asyncio.component import Component, run
from asyncio import sleep
from autobahn.asyncio.wamp import ApplicationSession, ApplicationRunner

@comp.on_join
async def joined(session, details):
    print("Connected to websocket")

    def on_message(msg):
        msg = json.loads(msg)
        print(msg)

    def some_rpc(with_data):
        print("Doing something with the data")
        return json.dumps({'status': 'OK'})

    try:
        session.subscribe(on_message, u'some_pubsub_topic')
        session.register(some_rpc, u'some_rpc_call')
        print("RPC and Pubsub initialized")

    except Exception as e:
        print("could not subscribe to topic: {0}".format(e))

if __name__ == "__main__":
     run([comp])
```

However now I need to be able to connect to multiple regular TCP sockets :

```
class SocketClient(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, loop):
        self.data = b''
        self.loop = loop

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        print('connected')

    def data_received(self, data):
        print('Data received: {!r}'.format(data.decode()))

    def send(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        print('The server closed the connection')
        print('Stop the event loop')
        self.loop.stop()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

c=loop.create_connection(lambda: SocketClient(loop),
                              '192.168.0.219', 6773)
loop.run_until_complete(c)
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

The problem is that, when I combine both and do this :

```
def some_rpc(with_data):
    c.send('test')
    return json.dumps({'status': 'OK'})
```

It barks at me and tells me :

> StopIteration
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/autobahn/wamp/websocket.py", line
>   95, in onMessage
>       self._session.onMessage(msg)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/autobahn/wamp/protocol.py", line
>   894, in onMessage
>       on_reply = txaio.as_future(endpoint.fn, *invoke_args, **invoke_kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/txaio/aio.py", line 400, in
>   as_future
>       return create_future_error(create_failure())   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/txaio/aio.py", line 393, in
>   create_future_error
>       reject(f, error)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/txaio/aio.py", line 462, in reject
>       future.set_exception(error.value)   File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 365, in set_exception
>       raise TypeError("StopIteration interacts badly with generators " TypeError: StopIteration interacts badly with generators and cannot be
>   raised into a Future

Does anyone have any idea on how to call the send function from within the RPC call function ?

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
c=loop.create_connection(lambda: SocketClient(loop),
                              '192.168.0.219', 6773)
# [...]
def some_rpc(with_data):
    c.send('test')
    return json.dumps({'status': 'OK'})
```

`create_connection` [is a coroutine function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.create_connection), so `c` contains a coroutine object. Such object does have a `send` method, but one that is entirely unrelated to sending things over the network. After calling `create_connection`, you probably want to get the resulting transport with something like:

```
transport, ignore = loop.run_until_complete(c)
```

and then use [`transport.write()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#asyncio.WriteTransport.write), not `c.send()`.